# Calling a column with $ value spark sql

Tags: azure, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have a problem selecting a column name with $ in it.

For  example:

select a$a from x

This is getting read as a parameter in azure databricks

I have tried 'a$a', "a$a" and tilda a$a...Is there a way to select such column value in spark sql

Answer (score 3):

Use `` ` `` to escape the column name.

```sql
select `a$a` from x
```

Comment: yes I tried and it doesnt work with escape character( tilda)